# PHP Ajax Autofill

Tags: php, ajax, autofill

Basically I want to create something like this: http://www.easybib.com/cite/form/website

So when you enter an URL in the textbox above it will gather information from the page and put them as values of the other textboxes below.

How is this possible using AJAX and PHP? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not here so that people can write code for you. We have jobs for that. Give this a go, do some Googling and return once you have an issue and/or some code.

Answer (score 0):

Its not hard, but I dont want to write the code instead of you, but some starting point:

You need an html page and some javascript and a php file for ajax calls. You can start with jQuery ( http://jquery.com/ ), when you click the button you send an ajax request to the php file with the site url parameter (you read it from the textbox), and when the request finished, you populate the desired html area with the information.

In the php file, you read the url param what you sent via ajax, then you fetch the site source, for example with file_get_contents ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php ), then you can parse the html if everything succeed, and send it to the output in json, html, plaintext format (whatever you want).

Parse with SimpleXML for example ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php ).

There is bunch of tools and tutorials if you search with google.

Keywords: 'ajax + php', 'javascript dom manipulation', 'get site content php', 'parse html php', 'parse xml php', 'json'

Good luck.

Comment: I have an idea about the part about making AJAX calls and PHP to work in the background. What I'm not sure is how to get the information written in different textboxes after I get the contents using PHP. Can you clarify this part?

Comment: When you receive the information and populate the selection area, you have to store the site (subsite) details in javascript, and attach some event listeners. So when someone clicks on 'Select' in the list, you will know which site it is, and you can populate the form with these values.

Comment: for example you store the recieved info in an array (var sites = new Array()), and the site infos in simple objects:
sites.push({url: response.url, name: response.name}); Then when clicked an element, you will know which item is needed, so you can do: yourdomelementofUrl.value = sites[x].url; yourdomelementofName.value = sites[x].name;

experimental, you can figure it out now i think

Comment: I don't get it. How to attach event listeners? So, basically, after I make the AJAX call and get all the variables in the PHP file how am I going to put those variables as values of textboxes?

Comment: Ok I made the plan in my mind a bit. I'll try and tell you if anything exciting happens.

Comment: Because I dont see any code snippets of the current code, and I dont know what is the format of your response and your html, I cannot write anything. For event listeners read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html  or http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ if you use jquery . For DOM manipulation, type into google: 'javascript dom manipulation', and learn a bit.

Comment: I did the most of it. But now, only I can't get back variables from PHP. I need to get the variables in PHP into Javascript and show a message with those variables. For instance, we know that "data" in JQuery returns the value that PHP file prints on the screen, how can I return lets say $variable from PHP file. Something like $.data("variable") ???

Comment: I figured it out, no worries.

Comment: I would do it like this:
$output = Array(
  Array('url' => 'http://google.com', 'name' => 'Google'),
  Array('url' => 'http://mail.google.com'm 'name' => 'Gmail')
);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);

and in jquery: $.ajax({
  url: 'ajax.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    //you can iterate over data, if everything ok, its a valid js array/object [{url:"http://google.com",name:"Google"},{...}] so: data[0].url == "http://google.com"
  }
});

Comment: ehhe, this comment is ugly without formatting, but you can get it i think. Also you can accept my answers ;)